# How to extract the specific values given by the user in the previous intent and use it in the next one in dialogflow?

Tags: dialogflow-es

How to extract specific values given by the user in the previous intent and use it in the next one?

Like - in the first intent the bot asks the user whats your name?

Then the user gives their name and the next intent is triggered.

The next intent the bot should respond to the users name with Hi IDK how may i help you?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Dialogflow ES we can use the below approach to solve your problem.

Create an output context of the start/first intent to be triggered like DEFAULT WELCOME INTENT with the lifespan of the 500.

Use the #context-name.parameter in which you wanted to replace your parameters.

Let's take your example here.

**Step 1:** I have created an output context as a test with the 500 lifespan.

**Step 2:** Create a Name intent which captured the user name in the **Name** parameter

**Step 3:** I wanted to use the name in the confirmation intent, so In the confirmation intent I'll use **#test.Name**. So It'll replace with the captured name.

Ref: [Dialogflow Es: Parameters](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/intents-actions-parameters)

Just to update, with the Dialogflow CX you can directly use the session parameters to replace the captured parameters. ($session.params.parameter-id).

Let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: Thanks. Another query: How to make an intent get values from only a particular intent and not from any other intent.
For eg- 
there are three intent A, B &C. I want intent C to get values from only B and not A. Even if some training phrases are same of A&C after user answers to question in intent A it should go to B and then only it can go to C.

Comment: @IDK If answer provides solution, please accept it and upvote. If there is another question, please create new Stackoverflow thread.